# Template parse errors: 'mdb-icon' is not a known element

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4

I am using Angular 7 with Bootstrap 4.
I am getting below error in console.

> Uncaught Error: Template parse errors: 'mdb-icon' is not a known
>   element:
>
> 1. If 'mdb-icon' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
> 2. If 'mdb-icon' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
>      ("class="table-add float-right mb-3 mr-2">
>          
>            [ERROR ->]
>          
>         "): ng:///AppModule/AppComponent.html@9:10

app.module.ts-

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { MatTableModule, MatCheckboxModule } from '@angular/material'

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    MatTableModule,
    MatCheckboxModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { 
}
```

app.component.html

```
<div class="card">
  <h3 class="card-header text-center font-weight-bold text-uppercase py-4">Editable table</h3>
  <div class="card-body">
    <div id="table" class="table-editable">
      <span class="table-add float-right mb-3 mr-2">
        <a class="text-success" (click)="add()">
          <mdb-icon fas icon="plus" size="2x"></mdb-icon>
        </a>
      </span>
      <table class="table table-bordered table-responsive-md table-striped text-center">
        <tr>
          <th class="text-center">Person Name</th>
          <th class="text-center">Age</th>
          <th class="text-center">Company Name</th>
          <th class="text-center">Country</th>
          <th class="text-center">City</th>
          <th class="text-center">Sort</th>
          <th class="text-center">Remove</th>
        </tr>
        <tr *ngFor="let person of personList; let id = index">
          <td>
            <span (keyup)="changeValue(id, 'name', $event)" (blur)="updateList(id, 'name', $event)" contenteditable="true">{{person.name}}</span>
          </td>
          <td>
            <span contenteditable="true" (keyup)="changeValue(id, 'age', $event)" (blur)="updateList(id, 'age', $event)">{{person.age}}</span>
          </td>
          <td>
            <span contenteditable="true" (keyup)="changeValue(id, 'companyName', $event)" (blur)="updateList(id, 'companyName', $event)">{{person.companyName}}</span>
          </td>
          <td>
            <span contenteditable="true" (keyup)="changeValue(id, 'country', $event)" (blur)="updateList(id, 'country', $event)">{{person.country}}</span>
          </td>
          <td>
            <span contenteditable="true" (keyup)="changeValue(id, 'city', $event)" (blur)="updateList(id, 'city', $event)">{{person.city}}</span>
          </td>
          <td>
            <span class="table-up">
              <a class="indigo-text">
                <mdb-icon fas icon="long-arrow-alt-up"></mdb-icon>
              </a>
            </span>
            <span class="table-down">
              <a class="indigo-text">
                <mdb-icon fas icon="long-arrow-alt-down"></mdb-icon>
              </a>
            </span>
          </td>
          <td>
            <span class="table-remove">
              <button type="button" mdbBtn color="danger" rounded="true" size="sm" class="my-0" (click)="remove(id)">Remove</button>
            </span>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- Editable table -->


<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

angular.json-

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "AdminApp": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "prefix": "app",
      "schematics": {},
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/AdminApp",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css",
              "node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [],
            "es5BrowserSupport": true
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                  "maximumError": "5mb"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "AdminApp:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "AdminApp:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "AdminApp:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "src/karma.conf.js",
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [],
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ]
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "src/tsconfig.app.json",
              "src/tsconfig.spec.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "AdminApp-e2e": {
      "root": "e2e/",
      "projectType": "application",
      "prefix": "",
      "architect": {
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "AdminApp:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "AdminApp:serve:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json",
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "AdminApp"
}
```

Comment: Where do you add the bootstrap library? i don't saw it on your `app.module.ts`.

Comment: you are missing the import { IconsModule } from 'angular-bootstrap-md' Icons Module?

Comment: @AntoineClavijo i have added bootstrap globally using angular.json.

Comment: @SehaxX i couldn't find 'angular-bootstrap-md', can you please tell the module in which it is

Comment: I Mean where do you add your Bootstrap modules?

Comment: I haven't added then, can you please tell me where should I add

Answer (score 0):

To solve this issue, just add:

```
import { MDBBootstrapModule } from 'angular-bootstrap-md';
```

and to your imports list.

```
MDBBootstrapModule.forRoot()
```